# Use of %d in different print functions

Tags: python

In this example:

```
print("Det låg %d flugor i soppan" %3)
```

why does the `%d` become a `3` but when I try it in other cases it doesn't? And what does the `%3` do?

Comment: Please give examples of *"other cases"*

Comment: e.g. print("I am %d years old")  or print("I have %d dogs")

Comment: Because in the first example you give a parameter to substitute, and in those ones you don't?

Comment: Oh so the %d is swapped with whatever I put behind the % in the end!

Comment: Please read up about string formatting: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%` after string literal (enclosed in quotes) is for something called formatting. In string occurrence of `%d` is changed to number in decimal (`d` stands for decimal, `x` stands for hexadecimal, `f` for floating-point, etc.).

So your example it is equivalent to:

```
print("Det låg 3 flugor i soppan")
```

This is probably more useful example:

```
def print_number( n ):
    print( "Text with %d in it" % n )

print_number(3)
```

For more information on string formatting look here: [Old string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting)

Comment: Good explanation on an off-topic question. :-(